# How to make scrollable html table columns responsive using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not a web designer. I was trying to design a web layout with some scrollable columns which contains some data in the form of anchor tags which are loaded dynamically. I've designed a `html table` structure along with a style sheet to achieve this. Source code of this table is as shown below

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <!--COLUMN HEADERS -->
            <td id="titles" style="width: 50%">
                <b style="padding-left: 4%">CURRENCY</b>
                <b style="padding-left: 9%">COUNTRY</b> 
                <b style="padding-left: 8%">SECTOR</b> 
                <b style="padding-left: 4%">LOCATION COUNT</b>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 50%">
                <!--1st COLUMN TO HOLD COUNTRY NAMES -->
                <div id="column">
                    <div ng-repeat="currency in allCurrencies">
                        <a href=""
                            ng-click="filterProductByCurrency(currency); filterCountryByCurrency(currency); filterSectorByCurrency(currency)">
                            <span ng-bind="currency"></span> <br>
                        </a> 
                        <input type="hidden" name="currencyHolder" ng-model="selCurrency">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--2nd COLUMN TO HOLD CURRENCY NAMES -->
                <div id="column">
                    <div ng-repeat="country in allCountries">
                        <a href=""
                            ng-click="filterProductByCountry(country); filterSectorByCurrAndCtry(country)">
                            <span ng-bind="country"></span> <br>
                        </a> 
                        <input type="hidden" name="countryHolder" ng-model="selCountry">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--3rd COLUMN TO HOLD SECTOR NAMES -->
                <div id="column">
                    <div ng-repeat="sector in allSectors">
                        <a href="" ng-click="filterProductBySectors(sector); filterLocBySectors(sector)"> <span
                            ng-bind="sector"></span> <br>
                        </a> 
                        <input type="hidden" name="variantHolder" ng-model="selVariant">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--4th COLUMN TO HOLD LOCATION COUNT RANGE -->
                <div id="column">
                    <div ng-repeat="locCount in locationRangeValues">
                        <a href="" ng-click="filterProductByRange(locCount)"> 
                        <span ng-bind="locCount"></span> <br>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

And the `CSS` styling for class `coulmn` is as shown below

```
#column {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    float: left;
    width: 14%;
    height: 125px;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
}
```

And `CSS` styling for class for `titles` is as given below

```
#titles{
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    color: #069; 
    fill: #069;
}
```

This works fine, but the issue with this setup is it's not responsive. I've interagted bootstrap within my application. Is there any way to make this setup more responsive using bootstrap? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

To make any table responsive just place the table inside a `<div>` element and apply the class `.table-responsive` on it, as demonstrated in the example below:

```
<div class="table-responsive"> 
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Row</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Biography</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Carter</td>
                <td>johncarter@mail.com</td>
                <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet…</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Peter</td>
                <td>Parker</td>
                <td>peterparker@mail.com</td>
                <td>Vestibulum consectetur scelerisque…</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Rambo</td>
                <td>johnrambo@mail.com</td>
                <td>Integer pulvinar leo id risus…</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

see working ex [here](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26318/)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this, but no luck. Main problem is when I shrink the browser, the column headers and columns go for a toss and loose their alignment. Do you have any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0):

There are way to change the td to div by using jQuery and css but not easy and you need to write different css for every table in your application, for more detail [see this](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/)

If you don't want to write css use RAHUL suggestion for scroll-able table for smaller screen by using bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

View this example. add bootstrap headers and responsive class to the divs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Table</h2>
  <p>The .table-responsive class creates a responsive table which will scroll horizontally on small devices (under 768px). When viewing on anything larger than 768px wide, there is no difference:</p>
  <div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Anna</td>
        <td>Pitt</td>
        <td>35</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>USA</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```